# Ember data - dynamic segments and query params together?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Using Ember 1.8.0 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.11, Ember store's `findQuery()` function doesn't seem able to handle dynamic segments, or at least I'm not able to find it in documentation anywhere.

For example, given the following routes

```
MyApp.Router.map ->
  @resource 'users', ->
  @resource 'user'
    path: 'users/:user_id'
  , ->
```

I know that

```
store.findQuery('user', {foo: 'bar'})
```

sends a GET request to

```
myapp.com/users?foo=bar
```

and also,

```
store.find('user', 1)
```

sends a GET request to

```
myapp.com/users/1
```

but now I want to send a GET request to

```
myapp.com/users/1?foo=bar
```

and I can't figure out how to do this or if it's even possible.  Hopefully I'm just missing something really obvious.  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: im stuck here too. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: unfortunately no. I ended up modifying the API on my backend to get the query I needed...

Answer (score 0):

This [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2584) will enable this scenario by introducing `queryOne` method, but is not yet merged into Ember.Data master.

Until then you could override `findQuery` method on `ApplicationAdapter`, such that `id` param would be passed as part of url and other params as query params. See [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/setavo/5/) for example.