# Ember query params for nested routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-model, ember-query-params

I have the url /tests/test-slug?extradata=data all my params are setup correctly within ember. When that extradata param is set the model updates with the new data from the (/tests/test-slug?extradata=data) response. Usually I would retrieve data using ember-model by doing:

```
model: function (params) {
  return App.Test.findQuery(params);
}
```

But with the query parameter added to this nested url its giving me 'test-slug' as a param with the extradata and making a request to the server with: ?tests_slug=test-slug&extradata=data

Is there anyway I can use query params and update my model on a nested route?

Edit: this post explains it a lot better than me:
[Ember data - dynamic segments and query params together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121840/ember-data-dynamic-segments-and-query-params-together)

Answer (score 3):

Extend your route's `params` with the parant route's `params` and send that into `.findQuery()`

`Ember.$.extend(params, this.paramsFor('parentRoute'));`

More: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_paramsFor

Answer (score 1):

This [PR](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/2584) should enable this scenario, but is not yet merged into Ember.Data.

Until then you could override `findQuery` method on `ApplicationAdapter`, such that `id` param would be passed as part of url and other params as query params. See [JsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/setavo/5/) for example.